# libcurl multipart post of variable length data objects

Tags: c++, http, post, libcurl, multipart

I'm having a difficult time with libcurl trying to adapt it to a particular situation. What I'm doing is essentially loading a variable number of objects into memory, performing various transforms on them, and then I want to uploaded them (serialized binary data of course) as part of a multi part post.

The part I'm struggling with is that I want to just add them as a part as they finish down this pipeline, then delete them after that particular part is posted.

I have thought about perhaps giving it a read function ptr, and on the callbacks perhaps manually feed the buffer with the part headers and data? This approach seems to be quite a hack.

I have tried the regular multipart approach (with multi-handle) but that seems to require all the data up front, or to be read from a file. Which i do not want libcurl to deal with.

To recap, I want to open a connection, start http multipart post request -> get in memory buffer -> add as post attatchment (multipart) -> send that off -> wait for next chunk of data -> repeat till done.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you trying to do this because the data you're trying to send it too big to fit in memory?

Comment: yes correct, the amount of data is variable, so it is possible that it may be very small, or very big. Either way I'm trying to keep the disk io very low.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`curl_formadd()`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html) function to prepare a `multipart/form-data` HTTP post, and then use the [`CURLOPT_HTTPPOST`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTHTTPPOST) option to actuallly send it.  `curl_formadd()` has a `CURLFORM_STREAM` option to enable use of the connection's `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` callback so you can custom-stream each multipart's data.